# How to register user control events when loaded dynamically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, telerik

I have a .aspx page with two drop downs that control which user control is dynamically added to the page using a placeholder. I have two drop downs that the user selected the value on one and loads the other. I have the second drop down value being passed to load the proper user control. Right after the user selects a value from the second drop down the user control shows that it has loaded but when the user clicks the drop down list on the user control the selectedIndexChanged event doesn't fire on the first selection and the value the user selected isn't retained. Once the user selects a value the page seems like it posts back and the value is stored and shows properly in the drop down list on the second selection. Here is my .aspx page that i have simplified to show the two drop downs and the code behind below it.

```
<%@ Page Title="Add New Property" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"  MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="addProperty.aspx.vb" Inherits="project.addProperty" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Clients/lodging.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="lodging" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<style type="text/css">
    .auto-style1 {
        height: 20px;
    }
 </style>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadAjaxPanel1">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadAjaxPanel1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" UpdatePanelCssClass="" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>

<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server" Width="100%">
<table style="width:100%;">
   <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1" style="text-align: right">
            Property Type</td>
        <td>
            <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="dd_ID_Const_PropertyType" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True"  Skin="WebBlue" DataSourceID="sql_getPropertyType" DataTextField="PropertyType" DataValueField="ID_Const_PropertyType" AutoPostBack="True" RenderMode="Auto" CausesValidation="False">
               <Items >
                    <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Select Property Type..." Value=0 />
                </Items>
            </telerik:RadDropDownList>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style4" style="text-align: right">Property Subtype</td>
        <td>
            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="dd_ID_Const_PropertySubType" Runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="true"
                Skin="WebBlue" DropDownAutoWidth="Enabled" MaxHeight="250px" Width="300px"
                RenderMode="Auto" CausesValidation="False" >
                <Items>
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="First Select Property Type..." Value=0 />
                </Items>
            </telerik:RadComboBox>
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph_propertiesSubType" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
</table>
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
</asp:Content>
```

here is my code behind for the aspx page. It is much more complex than this but i tried to make it easy to understand what I was doing. This code is when the user selects a value from the second drop down on the parent page (didn't include the selected index change code for the first drop down because that is working correctly)

```
     Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If IsPostBack Then
        Select Case ("Session")propertySubType
            Case 1
                ph_propertiesSubType.Controls.Add(lodgingControl)
            Case Else
                ph_propertiesSubType.Controls.Clear()
        End Select
    End If   
End Sub

     Private Sub dd_ID_Const_PropertySubType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e   As RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs) Handles dd_ID_Const_PropertySubType.SelectedIndexChanged

    ("Session")propertySubType = 1


    'add property subtype indexes to reference
    Select Case ("Session")propertySubType
        Case 1
            ph_propertiesSubType.Controls.Add(lodgingControl)           
        Case Else
            ph_propertiesSubType.Controls.Clear()
    End Select

End Sub
```

once the user selects the proper value the user control is dynamically added to the page. Here is my user control code.

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="lodging.ascx.vb" Inherits="project.lodging" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>

<style type="text/css">
    .auto-style1 {
        height: 25px;
        text-align: right;
    }
    </style>

<table>
<tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">Interior or Exterior Room Entrance</td>
            <td>
                <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="dd_ID_Const_RoomEntrance" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                    AppendDataBoundItems="True" CausesValidation="False" Skin="WebBlue" 
                    SelectedText="Select Market Type..." SelectedValue="0">
                    <Items>
                        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Select Market Type..." Value="0" Selected="True" />
                    </Items>
                </telerik:RadDropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sql_roomEntrance" runat="server" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT ID_Const_RoomEntrance, roomEntrance, Active
FROM Const_RoomEntrance
WHERE Active = 'True'
ORDER BY roomEntrance ASC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And the code behind for the user control. I init my database values and they load correctly. The problem i am having is that when the user goes to the drop down list right after the user control loads on the page the on selected index event doesn't trigger the user control drop down list value the first time. Its like the events haven't been registered and I am wondering how to register them. or how to raise the event that might not have been loaded completely. I have my auto post backs set its like my page structure loads but the code doesn't come in with it until another postback. When i set my breakpoints on the selectedIndexChange event they don't get fired on first selection, which I would think means they aren't available or loaded initially, but the breakpoint does get hit on the second selection.

```
 Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Imports System.Data.Sql
    Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Imports System.Data
    Imports System
    Imports System.Data.OleDb
    Imports System.Collections.Generic
    Imports System.Text
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Web

    Imports Telerik
    Imports Telerik.Web
    Imports Telerik.Web.UI

Public Class lodging
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
    Dim querystring As String = ""
    Dim tempTable As New DataTable
    Dim currentDate As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Private Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        dd_ID_Const_RoomEntrance.DataSource = sql_roomEntrance
        dd_ID_Const_RoomEntrance.DataTextField = "roomEntrance"
        dd_ID_Const_RoomEntrance.DataValueField = "ID_Const_RoomEntrance"
        dd_ID_Const_RoomEntrance.DataBind()
End Sub

Public Sub dd_ID_Const_RoomEntrance_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As DropDownListEventArgs) Handles dd_ID_Const_RoomEntrance.SelectedIndexChanged

        If dd_ID_Const_RoomEntrance.SelectedValue <> 0 Then
            Session("lodgingRoomEntrance") = dd_ID_Const_RoomEntrance.SelectedValue
        Else
            Session("LodgingRoomEntrance") = 0
        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I declared my controls in the public class section of my .aspx page like this:

```
Dim lodgingControl As UserControl = DirectCast(Page.LoadControl("~/Clients/lodging.ascx"), UserControl)
```

within the aspx page in the page_Init section i simply added an id to the control like this:

```
  lodgingControl.ID = 1
```

and the controls fire on the first selection. I don't know if this is the correct way to do this but my controls seem to be passing their events now.

```
Public Class addProperty
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Dim lodgingControl As UserControl = DirectCast(Page.LoadControl("~/Clients/lodging.ascx"), UserControl)

Private Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

        lodgingControl.ID = 1
        shoppingCenterControl.ID = 2

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically created controls MUST have IDs and they must not change between postbacks.

Also, try loading them in Page_Init, if possible, so that they are available before the ViewState and the ClientState load.

Third thing is, do not use AJAX settings for a RadAjaxPanel, remove one of them: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-controls-in-ajaxpanel-and-ajaxsettings.html.